# Android: How to control the Ripple effect in a RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, material-design, ripple

I am using a custom RecyclerView. In my RecyclerView row having two item one TextView and an ImageView. When I click the TextView that row item is showing the ripple effect.I put the ripple effect for that layout, so when clicking a Textview showing the ripple effect.

When I click the Image that shpwing on the right corner of the row, then also the ripple effect is showing the entire layout for that row. I want control that.

I want ripple effect only when I press the TextView/Layout. When I press the image I want control the ripple effect, ripple effect should only in that Image

Layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_subdistributorItem"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="-10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@drawable/list_background_with_shadow"
    android:paddingLeft="2dp">

    <com.flexiSupport.RippleView
        xmlns:ripple="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        ripple:rv_type="rectangle"

        >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_activeSubdistributor"
        android:layout_width="18dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"

        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:src="@drawable/offline"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_RechargeSubdistributor"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="15dp"

        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/recharge_text"
        android:text=""/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_subdistributor"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_activeSubdistributor"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/txt_RechargeSubdistributor"
        android:paddingLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_subDistributorName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:text="Subdistributor 1"
            android:maxLength="22"
            android:typeface="sans"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_subDistributorId"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_subDistributor_number"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:text="99999999"
            android:maxLength="22"
            android:typeface="sans"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            />
        </LinearLayout>
    </com.flexiSupport.RippleView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my layout show as

[image]

Can any one please help me to control the ripple effect

Answer (score 0):

Try giving this background to the view which has to have the ripple effect,

android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"